# filtering a dataset dependant on a value within a string

Tags: r, sum, filtering, analytics

I am currently working with Google Analytics and R and have a query I hope someone can help me with.

I have exported my data from GA into R and have it in a dataframe ready for processing.

I want to create a for loop which goes through my data and sums a number of columns in my dataframe if one column contains a certain value.

For example, my dataframe looks like this

[image: datatable]

I have a list of ID's which are the individual 3 digit numbers, which I can use in a for loop.

My past experience of R I have been able to filter the list so that I have

```
data[data$ID == 341,] -> datanew
```

and I have found some code which can see if there is a certain string within a string producing a bool

```
grepl(value, chars)
```

Is there a way to link these up together so that I have a sum code similar to below

```
aggregate(cbind(users, conversion)~ID,data=datanew,FUN=sum) -> resultforID
```

Basically taking that data and for every 341 add the users and conversions..

I hope I have explained this the best way possible.

Thanks in advance

data table has 3 columns. ID, users, Conversion with the users and Conversion linked to the IDs.

Some ID's are on their own, so 341, others are 341|246 and some will have three numbers with them seperated by the |

Comment: You will need to either assemble a list of target 3dgit values or create an expanded dataframe where the cases like `341|246` get split and the records duplicated. You ar enot making any friends in these parts by pasting in a picture of the data. Very few of us are willing to build up a test dataset when you could have easily posted one with dput that could be cut-and-pasted.

Comment: Thanks, I am off my computer now. I did try to insert but it was having none of it. Apologies. Will sort in the morning. Was just thinking the duplication may be the easiest way. Can you give me a helping hand in how to go about that?

Answer (score 1):

```
# toy data
mydata = data.frame(ID = c("341|243","341|243","341|242","341","243",
                           "999","111|341|222"),
                    Users = 10:16,
                    Conv = 5:11)

#            ID Users Conv
# 1     341|243    10    5
# 2     341|243    11    6
# 3     341|242    12    7
# 4         341    13    8
# 5         243    14    9
# 6         999    15   10
# 7 111|341|222    16   11

# are you looking for something like below:
# presume you just want to filter those IDs have 341.
library(dplyr)
mydata[grep("341",mydata$ID),] %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum))

#            ID Users Conv
# 1 111|341|222    16   11
# 2         341    13    8
# 3     341|242    12    7
# 4     341|243    21   11
```

Comment: thanks. I have ran this and it works, however ideally I want it to be like Ananda has done where it seperates and sums each up. Thanks again though

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you may want to look at `cSplit` from my "splitstackshape" package.

Using @KFB's sample data (which is hopefully representative of your actual data), try:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(mydata, "ID", "|", "long")[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = ID]
#     ID Users Conv
# 1: 341    62   37
# 2: 243    35   20
# 3: 242    12    7
# 4: 999    15   10
# 5: 111    16   11
# 6: 222    16   11
```

Alternatively, from the Hadleyverse, you can use "dplyr" and "tidyr" together, like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydata %>% 
  transform(ID = strsplit(as.character(ID), "|", fixed = TRUE)) %>% 
  unnest(ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum))
# Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
# 
#    ID Users Conv
# 1 111    16   11
# 2 222    16   11
# 3 242    12    7
# 4 243    35   20
# 5 341    62   37
# 6 999    15   10
```

Comment: I don't really know what they want

Comment: Hi, this seems spot on in terms of what you have written. I am very grateful. However, as I am running the code you have written I get the following error Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "unnest"

Comment: @Gareth, You need the latest `tidyr` package.  Please do `install.packages("devtools"); devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")`

Comment: @KFB thanks I have done this but tidyr will just not install, I am getting errors suggesting need to download rtools and I can now not install packages using the install packages button in rshiny as it wants me to create a folder (not had this issue in the past) and when I click yes it just refires same message. Its a work pc so dont know if its soemthing to do with permissions. Thanks for help though

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
sumdf <- yourdf %>%
           group_by(ID) %>%
           summarise_each(funs(sum))
```

I'm not clear about the structure of your ID column, but if you need to just get the numbers you could try this:

```
library(tidyr)
newdf <- separate(yourdf, ID, c('id1', 'id2'), '|') %>%
         filter(id1 == 341)  # optional if you just want one ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two answers. The first being with subset and the second is with 'grep' using a string

## initial run

```
x1<-sample(1:4,10,replace=TRUE)
x2<-sample(10:40,10)
x3<-sample(10:40,10)

dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3))

for(i in unique(dat$x1)) {
    dat1<-subset(dat,subset=x1==i)
    z<-(aggregate(.~x1,data=dat1,FUN=sum))
    assign(paste0('x1',i),z)
}
```

#### with GREP

```
x1<-sample(letters[1:3],10,replace=TRUE)
x2<-sample(10:40,10)
x3<-sample(10:40,10)

dat<-as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3))

for(i in unique(dat$x1)) {
    dat1<-dat[grep(i,dat$x1),]
    z<-(aggregate(.~x1,data=dat1,FUN=sum))
    assign(paste0('x1',i),z) #this will assign separate objects as your aggregates with names based on the string
}
```